# Facebook Activity not loading correctly in facebook-sdk 4.4.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I want to integrate Facebook signin in my android app. I am using Facebook-sdk-4.4.0. Using the LoginManager class method. But I am facing problem on running the following code-

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());    
callbackmanager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

// Set permissions
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions((Activity)getContext(), Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));

LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackmanager,
        new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject userInfo, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                                try {
                                    FacebookClientController.setUserId(userInfo.optString(ID));
                                    FacebookClientController.setDisplayName(userInfo.optString(NAME));
                                    FacebookClientController.setEmailAddress(userInfo.optString(EMAIL));
                                    JSONObject picJson = userInfo.getJSONObject(PICTURE).getJSONObject("data");
                                    FacebookClientController.setProfilePicUrl(picJson.optString("url"));
                                    Log.d(LOGTAG, "\nUsername :" + FacebookClientController.getDisplayName());
                                    Log.d(LOGTAG, "\nEmail :" + FacebookClientController.getEmailAddress());
                                    Log.d(LOGTAG, "\nUserId :" + FacebookClientController.getUserId());
                                    Log.d(LOGTAG, "\nProfilePicUrl :" + FacebookClientController.getProfilePicUrl());
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Log.d(LOGTAG, "Json Error");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                );
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString(FIELDS, FB_REQUEST_FIELDS);
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                GraphRequest.executeBatchAsync(request);

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Login successful" + loginResult.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(LOGTAG, "On cancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d(LOGTAG, error.toString());
            }
        });
}
```

[image: I am getting left Facebook activity in my app instead of right one]

I am getting the left screen in my app instead of the right screen which should come on running the above code. Can anyone tell me where can be the problem?
Logcat:

> --------- beginning of /dev/log/main
>
> I/AppHost.Android(10873): Registered listener for handling
>   onActivityResult: com.example.office.docsui.common.SignInController$5
>
> --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
>
> I/ActivityManager(  449): START u0 {act=NATIVE_WITH_FALLBACK
>   cmp=com.example.office.powerworld/com.facebook.FacebookActivity (has
>   extras)} from pid 10873
>
> I/TelemetryLifeCycleState(10873): Activity Pause Start.
>   Activity:1099625720,PPTActivity, AppState=3
>
> I/ActivityManager(  449): START u0 {act=NATIVE_WITH_FALLBACK
>   cmp=com.example.office.powerworld/com.facebook.FacebookActivity (has
>   extras)} from pid 10873
>
> I/TelemetryLifeCycleState(10873): Activity Pause End.
>   Activity:1099625720,PPTActivity, AppState=2
>
> I/TelemetryLifeCycleState(10873): Activity Created.
>   Activity:1107534680,com.facebook.FacebookActivity
>
> I/AppHost.Android(10873): onActivityStarted,
>   foregroundActivityCount=1, mEventsEnabled= true, mResumeEnabled=false
>
> I/AppHost.Android(10873): this is not an office
>   activity::com.facebook.FacebookActivity
>
> I/TelemetryLifeCycleState(10873): Activity Resume Start.
>   Activity:1107534680,com.facebook.FacebookActivity, AppState=2
>
> I/TelemetryLifeCycleState(10873): Activity Resume End.
>   Activity:1107534680,com.facebook.FacebookActivity, AppState=3,
>   suspensionTime=54215
>
> I/TelemetryLifeCycleState(10873): Activity Pause Start.
>   Activity:1107534680,com.facebook.FacebookActivity, AppState=3
>
> I/TelemetryLifeCycleState(10873): Activity Pause End.
>   Activity:1107534680,com.facebook.FacebookActivity, AppState=2
>
> I/TelemetryLifeCycleState(10873): Activity Created.
>   Activity:1107673504,com.facebook.FacebookActivity
>
> D/dalvikvm(10873): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2064K, 20% free 8974K/11096K,
>   paused 27ms, total 30ms
>
> I/AppHost.Android(10873): onActivityStarted,
>   foregroundActivityCount=1, mEventsEnabled= true, mResumeEnabled=false
>
> I/AppHost.Android(10873): this is not an office
>   activity::com.facebook.FacebookActivity
>
> I/TelemetryLifeCycleState(10873): Activity Resume Start.
>   Activity:1107673504,com.facebook.FacebookActivity, AppState=2
>
> I/TelemetryLifeCycleState(10873): Activity Resume End.
>   Activity:1107673504,com.facebook.FacebookActivity, AppState=3,
>   suspensionTime=54303
>
> D/mali_winsys(10873): new_window_surface returns 0x3000
>
> D/mali_winsys(10873): new_window_surface returns 0x3000
>
> D/mali_winsys(10873): new_window_surface returns 0x3000
>
> D/mali_winsys(10873): new_window_surface returns 0x3000
>
> I/Keyboard.Facilitator(  614): onFinishInput()
>
> I/ActivityManager(  449): Displayed
>   com.example.office.powerworld/com.facebook.FacebookActivity: +346ms
>
> I/ActivityManager(  449): Displayed
>   com.example.office.powerworld/com.facebook.FacebookActivity: +346ms
>
> D/mali_winsys(10873): new_window_surface returns 0x3000
>
> D/mali_winsys(10873): new_window_surface returns 0x3000
>
> I/K2_ULS  (10873): 07/21/2015 17:24:38.293    PPTDROID
>   (0x2a79)  0x40066154  Example powerworld  AppHost
>   PLM   a2k0b   Medium  PauseHandlerActivityLifecycleCallbacks:onActivitySaveInstanceState
>   called
>
> I/Keyboard.Facilitator(  614): onFinishInput()
>
> W/InputMethodManagerService(  449): Window already focused, ignoring
>   focus gain of:
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4227f090
>   attribute=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@423ba3a8, token =
>   android.os.BinderProxy@41f633d8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
LoginButton loginButton;
CallbackManager callbackManager;

FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email"));

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            profile.getProfilePictureUri(315, 315);
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

and override below method

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);         
}
```

and define this in menifest

```
<activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
```

Comment: Whats the use of seesionutilmanager its not a part of facebook-sdk?

Comment: Yes there is no use of it . Please now check it

Comment: I tried your above code but I am still getting that blank activity.

Comment: Yes I have defined that's why its able to show the activity but its not able to load the contents. I checked the logcat as well but everything seems normal there

Comment: When I install facebook app then new facebook activity comes but it gets cancelled on its own.

Comment: Please print log for it

Comment: Please check the changes in the question