# NullPointer with using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

I using Facebook SKD in my app and I have next error:

My `callBackmanager` in `onActivityResult()` method is null and I get `NullPointerException`

This is my code:

```
parent.findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button).setOnClickListener(this);
```

Where
`R.id.fb_login_button` - my custom button for fb.

When I click this button, my listener call this method:

```
private void onFacebookButtonClick() {

    initFacebook(getView());
    mFacebookLoginButton.performClick(); // this is button from SDK, Visibility - GONE
}
```

And this `initFacebook(View parent)` method:

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

mFacebookLoginButton = (LoginButton) parent.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
mFacebookLoginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
mFacebookLoginButton.setFragment(this);
mFacebookLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

        String userId = loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();
        trySocialLogin(userId, Constants.PROVIDER_FACEBOOK);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.e("FB", "onCancel()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

And this code from `onActivityResult()`:

```
callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); // callbackManager is null here - why?
```

Add logcat:

```
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.nashkvartal/com.nashkvartal.StartScreenActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=129742, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.nashkvartal/com.nashkvartal.StartScreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.facebook.CallbackManager.onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3287)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3318)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2661)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1512)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5691)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=129742, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.nashkvartal/com.nashkvartal.StartScreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.facebook.CallbackManager.onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3887)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3269)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3318)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2661)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1512)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5691)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.facebook.CallbackManager.onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
       at com.nashkvartal.fragments.LoginFragment.onActivityResult(LoginFragment.java:105)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:176)
       at com.nashkvartal.StartScreenActivity.onActivityResult(StartScreenActivity.java:74)
       at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6344)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3883)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3269)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3318)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2661)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1512)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5691)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

**UPD - added onActivityResult() full code**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {

    if (currentProvider == Constants.PROVIDER_FACEBOOK) {           
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); // I catch NullPointer here
    } 

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: post your logcat here

Comment: @ArtemShevchenko Currently only that code is their in `onActivityResult` as i can see in your Code?

Comment: @jaydroider sorry, what is OP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31530346/4749098 please see this. I have already posted it.

Comment: @ArtemShevchenko I mean your code is only this stuff?

Comment: @ArtemShevchenko Could you show me your full `override` `onActivityResult` code.

Comment: @jaydroider - done, look UPD

Comment: @ArtemShevchenko Check my answer may be it solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

> As per newer Facebook SDK. You should `override` `onActivityResult` with `super`.

**For newer SDK use:**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}
```

> And make sure For the login to work, Your `onActivityResult()` method should be outside the `FacebookCallback` anonymous class.

**EDIT 1**

> As from your code you need to init SDK before `setContentView`. Currently in your code it is called below `setContentView` so change it.

**Like this.**

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_screen);
```

Comment: make sure For the login to work, Your onActivityResult() method should be outside the FacebookCallback anonymous class.

Comment: @ArtemShevchenko Have you init facebookSDK `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize` as i can't be able to see that in your code ?

Comment: @ArtemShevchenko Then it should work i think. Could you show me full activity code.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1B4JNhesT_HGPUrd8qxituSLOvVCrvv6Rc8xb99lDtyI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @ArtemShevchenko Check my EDIT 1 apply that it should work then.

Comment: how about move this line to Application?

Comment: Move it in your `Base Activity` it self.@ArtemShevchenko